# Flutter App stuck at "Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'

Tags: flutter

My flutter app when run from VScode is always stuck at running-gradle-task-assembledebug

When I run flutter run -v in command prompt, it works but not from VSCode. This issue seems to have come since last week.
Tried ./gradlew clean and ./gradlew clean build, this works sometimes and buils from vscode

Deleted and created a new emulator device and also tried many suggestions online

Output from  flutter doctor -v

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.8.1, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1415], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 2.8.1 at E:\Flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 77d935af4d (4 weeks ago), 2021-12-16 08:37:33 -0800
    • Engine revision 890a5fca2e
    • Dart version 2.15.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at E:\sdk\Android
    • Platform android-31, build-tools 30.0.2
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = E:\sdk\Android
    • Java binary at: F:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
    • Android Studio at F:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189)

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • AOSP on IA Emulator (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 97.0.4692.71
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 96.0.1054.62

• No issues found!
```

created a brand new flutter project and did gradlew clean and got below messages for gradlew clean --warning-mode all

```
> Configure project :app
Adding a Configuration as a dependency is a confusing behavior which isn't recommended. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. If you're interested in inheriting the dependencies from the Configuration you are adding, you should use Configuration#extendsFrom instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration:extendsFrom(org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration[]) for more details.
        at build_59yj46qtreisbbowxqfuhj29p$_run_closure3.doCall(D:\MobileDevelopment\GitRepo\jigsaw\android\build.gradle:26)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
The AbstractArchiveTask.destinationDir property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Please use the destinationDirectory property instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask:destinationDir for more details.
        at FlutterPlugin$_addFlutterTasks_closure20$_closure44.doCall(E:\Flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle:833)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)
The AbstractArchiveTask.archiveName property has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. Please use the archiveFileName property instead. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.AbstractArchiveTask:archiveName for more details.
        at FlutterPlugin$_addFlutterTasks_closure20$_closure44.doCall(E:\Flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle:834)
        (Run with --stacktrace to get the full stack trace of this deprecation warning.)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date
```

Running gradlew build gives

```
> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libflutter.so.

> Task :app:stripProfileDebugSymbols
Unable to strip the following libraries, packaging them as they are: libapp.so, libflutter.so, libvmservice_snapshot.so

> Task :app:lint FAILED
Ran lint on variant debug: 3 issues found
Ran lint on variant release: 3 issues found
Ran lint on variant profile: 3 issues found
Wrote HTML report to file:///D:/MobileDevelopment/GitRepo/jigsaw/build/app/reports/lint-results.html
Wrote XML report to file:///D:/MobileDevelopment/GitRepo/jigsaw/build/app/reports/lint-results.xml

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.
> Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

  Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
  ...
  android {
      lintOptions {
          abortOnError false
      }
  }
  ...
  Errors found:

  D:\MobileDevelopment\GitRepo\jigsaw\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:5: Error: Class referenced in the manifest, com.example.jigsaw.${applicationName}, was not found in the project or the libraries [MissingClass]
          android:name="${applicationName}"
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~



* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 2m 26s
94 actionable tasks: 90 executed, 4 up-to-date
```

Redownloaded flutter 2.8 sdk from google official docs which also has dart in it and retried.

Answer (score 1):

It's due to your gradle is downloading it's version but sometimes it's speed download too low and won't be downloaded, you can fix it :

first check your gradle version in root of your project :

```
<project name> > android > gradle > wrapper > gradle-wrapper.properties
```

and check distributionUrl , you will see which gradle version is using in project and is downloading , so you should download that version in this link https://services.gradle.org/distributions/

after you download, copy and go to this directory :

```
C:\Users\<user name>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle <your version>\<a file with weird name>\
```

paste and unzip your downloaded file here.

it works for me every time I hope for you too.
let me know if there is any question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My gradle version is 6.7.1-all.zip in the gradle-wrapper.properties. When I went to C:\Users\<user name>\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle <your version>\<a file with weird name>\  , it already had the same version zipped and unzipped both
,

Answer (score 1):

I did solve the problem by first executing

flutter clean

and then, in order to recompile the project daet files

flutter pub upgrade